# Need some information on DNS bypass proxies?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, proxy

I have recently been researching about products that allow users to evade geo-blocking and i have come across:

- DNS "Proxies" like Tunlr [:link here:](https://github.com/corporate-gadfly/Tunlr-Clone)

I believe this is the best solution for me because I just need to use the proxy for the validation but not for the actual streaming of the content eg.Hulu or Netflix.

What I am having trouble with is understanding what is being said with regards to the Tunlr documentation (provided in the 'link here' hyperlink).

I am wondering whether or not I can recreate the router mechanism on the VPN itself or completely disregard it

Sum up:

- +Can I disregard the router and just connect directly to the VPN
- Does this kind of DNS based service decrease the server bandwidth as video content does not need to travel through the server.
- Is there another way to reroute connections without using a home router
- Can someone please clarify what the 'instructions' are telling me to do?Most importantly the 'Tomato based router'.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about your statement "I believe this is the best solution for me because I just need to use the proxy for the validation but not for the actual streaming of the content eg.Hulu or Netflix." ?  This does not make sense to me as most "regional only" sites use the IP address the request COMES FROM - possibly in addition to using DNS to route requests.

That is to say there are 2 components to the problem -

1. Modify your apparent IP address to be in the "allowed" zone.  This is typically done
   with a VPN or proxy server.  In the case of Tunlr it appears to be a kind of proxy
   they are running, and using DNS to route too.
2. Ensure your DNS requests are resolving appropriately - ie you are not fighting with a
   Content Delivery Network (CDN)

There is nothing magical about DNS lookups, and you can use any nameserver which will let you. You can also run your own or even use a hosts file to force lookups if you know the IP addresses you wish domains to resolve too.

Having looked at "tunlr.net", I am skeptical that it does what it claims - Specifically if you look at the "How does it work" section in tunlr.net/faq it says "Tunlr is transparently creating a network tunnel from your location to our U.S.-based servers. Any data that’s not directly related to the video or music content providers which Tunlr supports is not only left untouched, it’s also not even routed through Tunlr.".  This means that it is rerouting the requests THROUGH THE TUNLR systems [equivalent to using a VPN, but probably doing it by tricking DNS and acting as a proxy]- IF YOU DON'T HAVE SERVERS/SERVICE/VPN IN THE AREA BEING GEO-BLOCKED, YOU WON'T GET ROUND THE BLOCK.